# how to subtype records with erlang's compiler approval?

Tags: erlang, compiler-warnings, record

I am trying to define a record #a and a record #b such that #b extends #a, so that I can treat #b (and other subtypes of #a) as #a in some situations. The compiler, though, does not like it and keeps trying to guess the record type based on the first access I make to it. The following code triggers the warning.

```
-module(sandbox).  
-record(a,{alfa,beta}).  
-record(b,{alfa,beta,gama}).  
-export([test/0]).
test() ->  
    A = #b{alfa=1,beta = 2,gama=3},  
    self()!{msg,A},  
    receive  
    {msg,Msg} ->  
        Alfa = Msg#b.alfa,
        Beta = Msg#b.beta,
        case is_record(Msg,b) of
            true ->
                Gama = Msg#b.gama;
            false->                  %% Warning. Erlang assumes that Msg is a #b and therefore this will never match.
                Gama = []
        end
end,
io:format("~p ~p ~p",[Alfa,Beta,Gama]).


test1() ->
A = #b{alfa=1,beta = 2,gama=3},
self()!{msg,A},
receive
    {msg,Msg} ->
        Alfa = Msg#a.alfa,
        Beta = Msg#a.beta,
        case is_record(Msg,b) of
            true ->                  %% Warning. Erlang assumes that Msg is an #a, and therefore this will never match.
                Gama = Msg#b.gama;
            false->
                Gama = []
        end
end,
io:format("~p ~p ~p",[Alfa,Beta,Gama]).
```

Is there anyway I can use this subtyping and make the compilation warning go away?
Thanks.

Comment: If you structure your programm around inheritance you are not doing it the Erlang way.  Thats simply not how you would do something in Erlang. Don't use any OOP like experimental features before you grok the rest of the language ... please!

Comment: I actually really need this for interfacing with my SQL database model. We have a graph of objects, and a lot inherit from each other. I don't see why they couldn't add inheritance support to records. It would just save us the trouble of having to redefine a bunch of fields for every similar record. I ended up making the first field in each record the parent instead; that works OK for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this can work, because "-record(a,{alfa,beta})." is sort of a template for "{a, alfa, beta}" and "-record(b,{alfa,beta,gama})." results in a tuple "{b,alfa,beta,gama}".

Have a look at http://erlang.org/doc/getting_started/record_macros.html#id66845 , please...

Comment: The record sintax now makes sense to me. But if I can't subtype records, how do you suggest that I efficiently include a common part in a message (that's what the record is being used for)? I will edit the post to properly phrase the question.

Comment: Actually, I figure that if I want to generically access a field that is common to different records I must access it using the tuple sintax and forget the record sintactic sugar. Does that sound right?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to answer earlier, and with an example, but work kept me quite busy... I hope I can do a small sample this evening, how I would do it. Basically I would use an array with different tuples, something like [{alfa, "alpha value"}, {beta, 42}, {gama, 'optional'}]... maybe put this thing into a record definition like "-record(common, {alfa, beta, extended =[]})." and put 'gama' and maybe a delta into the extended array. I am too new to Erlang to say which would be the "best" approach.

Comment: Well, here is my small sample... but it does things a little bit different... but maybe more the Erlang way... without OTP: https://github.com/bsmr/erlang-samples/blob/master/src/sandbox.erl

Answer (score 1):

If you want inheritance in Erlang use module inheritance:

```
-module(inh).
-extends(base).
```

Also useful "OOP" feature in Erlang is parameterized modules:

```
-module(param, [Id, Name]).
-compile(export_all).
id() -> Id.
name() -> Name.
```

and use it:

```
P = param:new(1, stas).
P:id(). % returns 1
P:name(). % returns stas
```

Maybe combination of these features helps you.

Comment: Should say "if you want inheritance in Erlang think twice if this is really the way to go".  `-extends()` is definitely not a feature to learn before "how records work".

Comment: I'd definitely avoid parameterized modules.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Parameterized modules is something I've been looking at as a way to load different implementations of the same building block in my system. Is this a situation where you would use it? As for the record sub-typing, I don't think it applies there.

Comment: Parameterized modules are removed in R16B (and onwards)